# trouble linking .js file and jquery to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to reproduce a hardcopy version of a jsfiddle I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/5fv9B/25/

I am having trouble getting the javascript to work. My HTML head has the following:

`<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="my-tabs.js"></script>`

"my-tabs.js" contains the javascript from the jsfiddle. Both files are in the same directory as the HTML file.

Comment: And you did download those files and place them in the same path as the current page, and check the filenames etc.

Comment: Do jquery-2.0.3.min.js and my-tabs.js both exist in the same directory as the file containing the HTML? *edit* nevermind, just saw your line at the bottom.

Comment: both files are in the same directory, yes paths are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle has the javascript executed onLoad - but your html has the script inside the head - which is where the difference lies.

Wrap all the code in your my-tabs.js with a

```
$(function() {
   /* your code here. */
});
```